# Why does the limit of my sum sometimes go underneath and others to the right?

Tags: spacing, letterspacing

I have the same summation but sometimes the bottom limit appears underneath as I want, and others it jumps to the right? Is there any way to ensure the limit sit underneath?

These sit to the right.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
g_2(\tau) &= 60 \sideset{}{'}\sum_{m,n} (m +n\tau)^{-4}
\\ g_3(\tau) &= 140 \sideset{}{'}\sum_{m,n} (m+n\tau)^{-6}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

While these sit underneath.

```
\begin{align}
g_2(T(\tau)) &= 60 \sideset{}{'}\sum_{m,n} \left( m +n\frac{(a\tau +b)}{(c\tau +d)} \right)^{-4}
\\ &= 60(c\tau +d)^{-4}\sideset{}{'}\sum_{m,n} (m(c\tau+d) + n(a\tau+b))^{-4}
\\ &= 60(c\tau +d)^{-4} \sideset{}{'}\sum_{m,n} ((md+nb) +(mc+na)\tau)^{-4}
\end{align}
```

Is it something to do with their environment?

Comment: see https://nl.sharelatex.com/learn/Display_style_in_math_mode

Answer (score 3):

This is because the `cases` environment switches maths to `\textstyle`. If you want `\displaystyle`, use the `dcases` environment  from  `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % already loads amsmath

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{dcases}
g_2(\tau) &= 60 \sideset{}{'}\sum_{m,n} (m +n\tau)^{-4}
\\ g_3(\tau) &= 140 \sideset{}{'}\sum_{m,n} (m+n\tau)^{-6}
\end{dcases}
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
g_2(T(\tau)) &= 60 \sideset{}{'}\sum_{m,n} \left( m +n\frac{(a\tau +b)}{(c\tau +d)} \right)^{-4}
\\ &= 60(c\tau +d)^{-4}\sideset{}{'}\sum_{m,n} (m(c\tau+d) + n(a\tau+b))^{-4}
\\ &= 60(c\tau +d)^{-4} \sideset{}{'}\sum_{m,n} ((md+nb) +(mc+na)\tau)^{-4}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]